# Video codec for making home videos smaller?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codecs, avconv, h264

Complete video beginner here.

I have a bunch of old videos in multiple formats and codecs - like birthday videos, undergrad random captures etc.
There is a large number of files that amount to ~25GB in total - all 720p or lesser likely 480p. I would like to make them smaller with minimal loss in quality.

I thought about re-encoding them using `avconv` or `ffmpeg` - I'm on **Ubuntu 15.04 64b** and [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/what-are-the-differences-and-similarities-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv) tells me they are actually different for my OS.

[An analysis](http://www.learningsolutionsmag.com/articles/1203/video-compression-secrets-smaller-files-better-quality) I found tells me `wmv` as a codec might give me smallest size without too much loss in quality. But, [other articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/en/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) say `h264` (enabled by the `libx264-dev` package) allows a lot of compression (**which I do not understand how to do wih minimal quality loss**).

How I get smaller files (with sample commands preferably) - wmv or compressed h264?

Answer (score 2):

## Example: H.264 video + stream copied audio in Matroska

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -c:a copy output.mkv
```

Anything WMV is a joke. H.264 video via the encoder `libx264` is your best bet right now. While H.265 looks good on paper the implementations just are not quite there yet for typical usage (unless your time is cheap because it is slow).

You basically only need to change `-crf` and `-preset`:

- Use the highest `-crf` value that still gives an acceptable quality. Range is a log scale of 0-51. 0 is lossless (huge files). Around 18 is considered visually lossless. 23 is default.
- Use the slowest preset you have patience for. They are: ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium [default], slow, slower, veryslow, placebo (ignore placebo; it's too slow for any potential significant advantage over veryslow).
- Now use the same `-crf` and `-preset` for the rest of your batch of videos.

The audio is being [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) instead of re-encoded because the vast majority of data will be video.

With all of that, I must point out that 25G is small and storage is cheap. If I were in this situation I'd probably just keep the original videos and not bother with re-encoding. Also, re-encoding may not help if the originals were encoded properly with a modern, efficient format.

## Also see

[FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

Comment: I will try this out and let you know. It's not just 25G, some of my friends also have the same situation, and these are files that we may never find time to look at again, but still have no heart to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Lord Neckbeard is right. WMV comperession is poor. The best compression available at the moment of writing is H.265

**Example: H.265 HEVC video + stream copied audio in Matroska**

`ffmpeg -i inputfile -c:a copy -c:v libx265 -preset veryfast -x265-params crf=25 -vf scale=-8:ih outputfile.mkv`

Quoting Lord Neckbeards accurate statements.

You basically only need to change -crf and -preset to match your quality and speed requirements:

Use the highest -crf value that still gives an acceptable quality. Range is a log scale of 0-51. 0 is lossless (huge files). Around 18 is considered visually lossless. 23 is default.

Use the slowest preset you have patience for. They are: ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium [default], slow, slower, veryslow, placebo (ignore placebo; it's too slow for any potential significant advantage over veryslow).*

```
    Now use the same -crf and -preset for the rest of your batch of videos."
```

The CRF scales for x264 and x265 do not correspond. x265 CRF 28 is supposedly equivalent to x264 CRF 23. But x265 is not yet as mature in its development as x264, so take that CRF equivalence with a pinch of salt.

I've been very happy with the compression and quality with the settings above. Adjust them to your liking.

Breaking down the command above:

-c:a copy copies the audio stream without re-encoding it.
-c:v libx265 chooses libx265 as the video codec
-crf is explained above as is -preset

scale=-8:ih avoids mangling the video beyond recognizability in the event that the source video isn't an exact multiple of 8 pixels in width (necessary for some input files)

Sources:

Experience

[Video codec for making home videos smaller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668962/video-codec-for-making-home-videos-smaller)

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16664/what-crf-or-settings-i-should-choose-for-h265-in-order-to-achieve-a-similiar-qua

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16664/what-crf-or-setting